# Unity Placing a UI on top of Cinemachine

Tags: unity, 2d, user-interface, cinemachine

I have cinemachine set up. I just need to place the UI on top of it. I can easily manage to make the canvas appear when there's only the main camera alone. However with Cinemachine, it appears that the virtual camera prevents the loading screen to be seen. The canvas in my hierarchy is named `loadingPanel` which is disabled until I trigger an event. Everything in the hierarchy has their layers set to `Default`, except canvas (`UI`) and the player (`Player`)

**I can trigger the event and set `loadingPanel` to active as well as load the next level but I can't see the loading screen. I could only see my tilemap/level before I switch to the next scene. I need to see my canvas / user interface.**

This is my hierarchy

[image: hierarchy tab]

Inspector

[image: loading panel inspector]

How do I see the `loadingPanel` when cinemachine is present?

Comment: I notice you set the UI canvas to be displayed only in the Main Camera. Did you try setting it to display on the CM vcam1 camera when it's active, or use the Overlay mode to draw over everything regardless of camera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to come back. Setting the Canvas panel back to `Overlay` mode did the trick.

Credits to DMGregory

Comment: Note that this is literally the very first parameter the Inspector exposes to you in the screenshot you shared. In future, please read the docs for the types you're using and try simple parameter substitutions like this yourself. Our general assumption is that you've made your very best effort to solve the problem yourself before deciding to take others' time by asking here.

Comment: okay. my bad. will do